# activity transition?

Tags: android

I have implemented one App which has many activities.. . I wanted to implement one activity as left and right and vice versa in fling transition manner between whole activity. For example: SO when you hit next there should be transition between next activity and when you hit previous there should be transition between previous . ....
I made transition successfully .. but have simple problem...what i am doing is, i get the data from the database and store it in cursor and i show it to user via activity..my problem is since i am using same activity to do the transition it will get the data from database every time....

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_summary);

//I am Trying to get the date here from database ,but it will be called everytime since this is oncreate() method.. I dont know How should i get the data from the database and should show it to user...

        final Intent intent=new Intent(this,SummaryActivity.class);
        Button previous=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button_Summary_previous);
       previous.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            System.out.println("I am in Previous");
            startActivity(intent);
            SummaryActivity.this.overridePendingTransition(
            R.anim.card_flip_left_in,
            R.anim.card_flip_right_out
            );
            finish();
        }
    });
       Button next=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button_Summary_next);
       next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            System.out.println("I am in Next");
            startActivity(intent);
            SummaryActivity.this.overridePendingTransition(
                    R.anim.card_flip_right_in,
                    R.anim.card_flip_left_out
            );
            finish();
      }
```

Any Help?

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better to take whatever data you need from the database when the application starts at the beginning,
store it in the SD card, or in memory of the phone and access it from there whenever you need it.

Comment: but that data can be changed any time...so while using the app user can put the data anytime in the database.. this activity is special used to show what user has entered in the database...

Comment: so u have some activities that user changes the data, and one activity to display the data fro db?

Comment: if yes, u can check if the user is about to enter the activity that the data from the database it will be displayed and then retrieve the data .

Answer (score 0):

why you need to finish your current activity after start another activity?

you should know after everytime you finish a activity, if you want to come back to the finished activity. the activity will be recreated since it was destroyed before.

just remove the finish() in your onClick method.